# present : past[past.length - 1] , this should return a single value but it is returning a full array like slice method does

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-reducer

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useReducer } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function reducer(state,action){ 
  const {past,present,future} = state
  switch(action.type){
    case 'ADD' : return {

      past : [...past,present],
      present : [...present,{id : Math.random(),name : action.payload}],
      future : [],
      canUndo : true,
      canRedo : false,
      
    }

    case "UNDO" : if(!state.canUndo) return state;
    return {
      present :past[past.length - 1], 
      past : past.slice(0,-1),
      future : [present,...future],
      canUndo : past.length > 1,
      canRede : true
    }
    case 'REDO' : return {
    
    }
    default: return state;
  }

}
function App(){
  const input = useRef();

  const initialState = {
    present : [],
    past : [],
    future : [],
    canUndo : false,
    canRedo : false,
  }

  const[items,dispatch] = useReducer(reducer,initialState);

  const addItem = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch({type : 'ADD', payload : input.current.value})
    input.current.value = '';
 
  }
  return(
    <div>
      <h1>Shopping list</h1>
      <form className='add-product' onSubmit={addItem}>
        <label htmlFOR='product'>product</label>
        <input ref={input} type='text' id='product'/>
        <button type='submit'>Add</button>
      </form>

      <div className='actions'>
        <button onClick={() => dispatch({type : 'UNDO'})}>Undo</button>
        <button onClick={() => dispatch({type : 'REDO'})}>Redo</button>
      </div><ul>
        {items.present.map(item => <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>)}
      </ul>

      
    </div>
  )
}



export default App;
```

Hello Everyone, i am having hard time understanding this concept

> present : past[past.length - 1]

So after adding a value, This should return a single value when I click on Undo button, but it is returning a full array except the last one, if anyone explains this concept I will be very thankful, why it is behaving like slice method

Comment: I think issue is with some of your operations where you're concatenating arrays like this: `[...past,present]` -> here, shouldn't it be `[...past,...present]`. Also, this `future : [present,...future]` should be: `future : [...present,...future]` . Right? I could be wrong, but that's what it seemed like, to me...

Comment: Running your code in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/present-pastpast-length-1-this-should-return-a-single-value-but-it-is-re-osmun) it seems to be running correctly (as I am understanding). What is the issue? Are you asking why `past[past.length - 1]` returns an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your post, you are asking why `past[past.length - 1]` returns an array instead of a single value.

The reason for this is because it ***IS*** returning a single value, the last element of the `past` array, and this value just happens to also be an array. In other words, your state, i.e. `present` is an array of values and you are maintaining "undo" and "redo" stacks. When a new item is added to the `present` array, the previous `present` array is added (`PUSHED`) to the `past` undo stack. When you undo this you are removing the last item (`POPPED`) from the `past` undo stack and replacing the current `present` array.

Example:

Initial state:

```
past: []
present: []
future: []
```

ADD 1: present is pushed into past (`[].push([]) -> [[]]`), 1 is pushed to present (`[].push(1) -> [1]`)

```
past: [[]]
present: [1]
future: []
```

ADD 2: present is pushed into past (`[[]].push([1]) -> [[], [1]]`), 2 is pushed to present (`[1].push(2) -> [1, 2]`)

```
past: [[], [1]]
present: [1, 2]
future: []
```

UNDO: present is pushed into future (`[].push([1, 2]) -> [[1, 2]]`), past is popped (`[[], [1]].pop() -> [[]]`) and set as present (`[1]`)

```
past: [[]]
present: [1]
future: [[1, 2]]
```

ADD 3: present is pushed into past (`[[]].push([1]) -> [[], [1]]`), 3 is pushed to present (`[1].push(3) -> [1, 3]`), future is cleared (`[]`)

```
past: [[], [1]]
present: [1, 3]
future: []
```

ADD 4: present is pushed into past (`[[], [1]].push([1, 3]) -> [[], [1], [1, 3]]`), 4 is pushed to present (`[1, 3].push(4) -> [1, 3, 4]`)

```
past: [[], [1], [1, 3]]
present: [1, 3, 4]
future: []
```

Note that any element entry in `past` or `future` arrays (*stacks*) is an array.

[image: Edit present-pastpast-length-1-this-should-return-a-single-value-but-it-is-re]

[image]

Comment: wow, thank you very much for explaining this deep, sorry for my bad english
i again have a one question,
suppose when i will use this `present :past[past.length - 1]` ... doesnt it will change the original present state to just 1 value

i mean suppose present have 3 items  present [ {1}, {2}, {3}]
now if i use `present :past[past.length - 1]`,  it will only return a singla array like [ {} ]
we are undoing only 1 value which is the last one {3}. in present array but by doing this
`present :past[past.length - 1]`, it will replace present with single array

Comment: please read this, i have tried to explain my 2nd question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69142118/present-pastpast-length-1-this-should-be-overwritten-by-a-single-value-but,

Comment: @AdanAli Your other question seems to be a duplicate of this question. `present` is *always* just a single value, i.e. the current value, while the `past` and `future` will *always* be an array (a "stack" essentially) of "current" values. All you are doing when you undo is move the current present value onto the top of the `future` stack and move the top of the `past` stack into the present value, and the opposite when you redo.

Comment: present have multiple items in it, whatever i click on `add` ..`items` is getting stored in `present`, that is why i am using `item.present.map(item => <li>{item}</li>` to show link items on browser